# ¿Estoy estructurando correctamente esta base de datos?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Es para una cosa muy muy sencilla.

Estoy haciendo una web muy simple donde se puede realizar un registro de usuario  y a continuación se da  un objeto para el inventario del usuario.

Por lo que entiendo debo crear una tabla "usuarios" con: codigo, nombre, password e inventario.
Crear una tabla inventario **para cada usuario** que se registre y otra tabla de objetos?

Donde me lío es si debo crear una tabla inventario **para cada** usuario o si existe otra manera mas eficiente.

Disculpad las molestias, estoy empezando a  aprender.

edito:

Intentaré explicarme mejor.
El funcionamiento sería el siguiente. El usuario se registra y se le asigna un inventario con un objeto. En un apartado de la página tendrá la oportunidad de conseguir más objetos que añadir a su inventario. En el código se ejecutaría una sentencia que añadiría una fila a la tabla inventario con el una clave foranea del objeto añadido y cantidad. Para tratar esto con diferentes usuarios debería crear una tabla inventario propia para cada usuario?

Comment: No me queda claro el problema, tienes usuarios, inventario y objetos ? puedes definir mejor que es lo que necesitas registrar?

Comment: Gracias por contestar, añadiré a la pregunta esta explicación.

El funcionamiento sería el siguiente.
El usuario se registra y se le asigna un inventario con un objeto.
En un apartado de la página tendrá la oportunidad de conseguir más objetos que añadir a su inventario.

En el código se ejecutaría una sentencia que añadiría una fila a la tabla inventario con el una clave foranea del objeto añadido y cantidad.

Para tratar esto con diferentes usuarios debería crear una tabla inventario propia para cada usuario?

Comment: Una sola tabla inventario que se relaciona con usuario y clases de objeto

Comment: Tienes que tener clara la cardinalidad, p.e un usuario tiene varios objetos de distinto tipo

Comment: Deberias leer sobre normalizacion de bases de datos, y sobre creacion de las mismas.. tienes conceptos erroneos y mas alla de esta pregunta, te van a llevar a dise;os erroneos. Hay una tabla usuarios (lo dijiste) y una tabla inventario (no una por usuario, una tabla unida por el id de usuario) y si fuera necesario una tabla objetos (y depende la cardinalidad, tablas auxiliares)

Comment: He repasado un poco el tema de normalización y he llegado a la conclusión de crear una tabla inventario con claves foraneas de usuario y objeto, además de un campo cantidad.
La relación sería de usuario tiene productos n:m. Según lo que interpreto en mis apuntes debo crear una tabla resultante de esa relación con las claves de las primeras, esa tabla sería precisamente el inventario.
Creo que me estoy acercando.

Comment: Así es , te falta tener claro lo que es un Objeto y un tipo de objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas dos tablas y una relación, me explico:

Contamos con Usuario y Objeto, estos son los elementos principales, por ende, las tablas. Después, con una relación N->N podemos asignar a los usuarios los objetos y generar así un inventario.

El esquema quedaría algo así:

- Usuarios: IdUsuario, codigo, nombre, password (No te recomiendo que este campo se guarde con este nombre ni en claro, siempre hasheado, si es una practica no pasa nada, pero tenlo en cuenta).
- Objetos: IdObjeto, Nombre, Tipo ...

Para la relación necesitas una tabla con las Foreing keys de las dos anteriores y para la cantidad existen dos maneras, o bien, insertar uno a uno y después contabilizar el numero de relaciones iguales o un campo cantidad, quedando así:

- Inventario: IdUsuario, IdObjeto, Cantidad(opcional)

Entonces para recuperar el inventario con:

```
SELECT U.NOMBRE, O.NOMBRE, I.CANTIDAD FROM USUARIOS U
LEFT JOIN INVENTARIO I ON I.IDUSUARIO = U.IDUSUARIO
LEFT JOIN OBJETOS O ON O.IDOBJETO = I.IDOBJETO
WHERE IDUSUARIO = <NUM_USUARIO>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a asimilar la información. Te lo agradezco enormemente.

Comment: si ha sido la respuesta que andabas buscando, es mejor que valides con el tic verde para que otros usuarios con las mismas dudas puedan ver la solucion, aparte de que te llevas un poco de reputación por dicha acción.

Comment: Hecho, gracias por avisar! no sabía como iba el sistema.